# Insert sequencia Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Pessoal boa noite estou querendo inserir dados em uma tabela , que tem uma sequencia criada, mas ao tentar inserir o dado com o nextval ele apresenta o seguinte erro

> Erro Erro de SQL: ORA-00911: caractere inválido
>
> 911. 00000 - "invalid character"

***Cause**: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
letters and numbers. $#_ are also allowed after the first
character. Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
any character other than a doublequote. Alternative quotes
(q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
Reference Manual.

```
CREATE TABLE CursoSequencia (
    cod_curso NUMBER(3),
    nome_curso VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    carga_hor NUMBER(3),
    CONSTRAINT cursoSquencia_cod_pk PRIMARY KEY(cod_curso)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE cod_curso INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1001;

INSERT INTO CursoSequencia VALUES(cod_curso.nextval, ‘AdministracaoOracle’,3);

INSERT INTO CursoSequencia VALUES(cod_curso.nextval, ‘AdministracaoSQLServer’,3);
```

Comment: Só pra confirmar... é PostgreSQL ou Oracle?

Comment: A chave tem tamanho de três a sequence começa de 1001 !?

Comment: @CamiloSantos o erro já confirma que é oracle. Felipe, acredito que você colocou a tag postgresql por engano.

Comment: George, fiz a remoção da *tag* pois o erro é referente à Oracle SQL. PostgreSQL não apresenta erros **ORA**.

Answer (score 6):

Olá [Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64585/felipe)!

Fazendo uma rápida tradução do erro apresentado, **ORA-00911**, sabemos que foram encontrados caracteres inválidos em sua *query* que está impedindo a sua execução. Porém, encontrei um outro pequeno problema na parte [DDL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262868/127729) de seu código.

Vou separar os problemas que encontrei no seu código em duas partes.

1. O no seu comando DML, em específico, na coluna `nome_curso VARCHAR2(30)`, do qual você está utilizando as aspas simples  <kbd>`‘`</kbd>  ao invés   <kbd>`'`</kbd> , note que visivelmente, o problema é justamente esse, você está utilizando as aspas simples no [padrão americano](http://blog.tiagopassos.com/2012/01/12/utilizando-o-teclado-padrao-americano-eua-com-acentuacao-e-pontuacao/) e isso resulta no conflito de caractere inválido. 
   Altere as aspas utilizadas nos valores characteres `‘AdministracaoOracle’` para `'AdministracaoOracle'`.
2. Note que a sua `SEQUENCE` foi definida para ter a contagem do seu valor inicial à partir do valor **1001**, logo, sabemos que esse valor se aplicará à um total de 4 caracteres ou mais. Ao definir a quantidade total de caracteres de sua **PK** para 3 digitos: `cod_curso NUMBER(3)`, você terá o erro ([ORA-01438](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0eec/1)), dessa vez ocasionado pelo total de caracteres retornado do `cod_curso.nextval`, justamente porque a `SEQUENCE` retornará um total de 4 dígitos e o permitido da sua coluna `cod_curso` está sendo 3 dígitos.

Resolvendo esses dois itens acima, você terá seu SQL funcionando normalmente.

Fontes:[docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e900.htm#ORA-00910), [dba-orable](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00911_invalid_character.htm).

Fiddle com as correções [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f499/6).

Comment: Ótimas observações Andre!

Comment: Agradeço David, estamos aqui para nos ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Se você criou uma sequence que irá fazer o auto incremento, no momento de fazer o insert não precisa informar o id, o banco irá adicionar automaticamente.

Portanto, basta fazer o seu insert dessa forma:

`INSERT INTO CursoSequencia (nome_curso, carga_hor) VALUES (‘AdministracaoSQLServer’,3);`

Comment: Na verdade depende Isaias. Ele só não precisa informar a coluna se ele criou uma triger before insert. Se apenas uma sequence foi criada ele tem que colocar a coluna ainda.