# O que são as siglas DDL, DML, DQL, DTL e DCL?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estava montando uma estrutura de permissões no banco (GRANT, REVOKE), quando achei este artigo e achei interessante compartilhar, ate mesmo para ter aqui no SOpt.

#### Questão original

- O que é DCL?

[Fonte](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/o-que-e-dcl/564671)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Pense assim, a linguagem SQL é uma só, porém ela é dividida em tipos de acordo com a funcionalidade dos comandos.
Os tipos da linguagem SQL são:

- **DDL** - Data Definition Language - Linguagem de Definição de Dados.
  São os comandos que interagem com os objetos do banco.

  - São comandos DDL : CREATE, ALTER e DROP
- **DML** - Data Manipulation Language - Linguagem de Manipulação de Dados.
  São os comandos que interagem com os dados dentro das tabelas.

  - São comandos DML : INSERT, DELETE e UPDATE
- **DQL** - Data Query Language - Linguagem de Consulta de dados.
  São os comandos de consulta.

  - São comandos DQL : SELECT (é o comando de consulta)
    <sub>Aqui cabe um parenteses. Em alguns livros o SELECT fica na DML em outros tem esse grupo próprio.</sub>
- **DTL** - Data Transaction Language - Linguagem de Transação de Dados.
  São os comandos para controle de transação.

  - São comandos DTL : BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT E ROLLBACK
- **DCL** - Data Control Language - Linguagem de Controle de Dados.
  São os comandos para controlar a parte de segurança do banco de dados.

  - São comandos DCL : GRANT, REVOKE E DENY.

#### Autor original

Luiz Fernando
[Fonte](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/o-que-e-dcl/564671)

Comment: Alguns lugares em que é relativo diferenciar a DQL da DML: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292433/64969; eu não gosto de dizer que são conjuntos diferentes, então eu prefiro dizer que as operações que alteram o banco são a DML removendo a DQL; em notação de conjuntos seria DML\DQL

Answer (score 18):

## Uma forma mais simples pra ser lembrado

O que diferencia as siglas é a letra do meio.

Como, por exemplo:

- **DML** = "**M**" do meio vem de **Manipulação**.
- **DDL** = "**D**" do meio vem de **Definição**.
- **DCL** = "**C**" do meio vem de **Controle**.
- **DTL** = "**T**" do meio vem de **Transação**.
- **DQL** = "**Q**" do meio vem de **"Qonsulta"**.

Comment: "Qonsulta" +1 haha