# java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

A minha inserção de chaves não está sendo feita.
E o erro que dá no console é:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2224)
    at dao.ChaveDAO.adicionar(ChaveDAO.java:27)
    at logicas.AddChave.executa(AddChave.java:26)
    at servlet.ControllerServlet.service(ControllerServlet.java:35)

A linha 27 de ChaveDAO:             ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
A linha 26 de AddChave:             dao.adicionar(chave);
A linha 35 de ControllerServlet:            String pagina = logica.executa(req, resp);
```

**Código ControllerServlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/sistema")

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String parametro = req.getParameter("logica");
    String nomeDaClasse = "logicas." + parametro;

    System.out.println("Lógica: " + parametro);
    System.out.println("Comando: " + nomeDaClasse);

    try {
        Class<?> classe = Class.forName(nomeDaClasse);
        Logica logica = (Logica) classe.newInstance();

        String pagina = logica.executa(req, resp);

        req.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(req, resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("A lógica causou uma exceção", e);
    }
}

}
```

**Código AddChave:**

```
public class AddChave implements Logica {
public String executa(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
    Chave chave = new Chave();
    ChaveDAO dao = new ChaveDAO();

    String idTexto = req.getParameter("id");

    String nome = req.getParameter("nome");
    // int numero = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("numero"));
    String numero = req.getParameter("numero");

    chave.setNome(nome);
    chave.setNumero(numero);

    if (idTexto == null || idTexto.isEmpty()) {
        dao.adicionar(chave);
    } else {
        chave.setId(Long.parseLong(idTexto));

        dao.alterar(chave);
    }

    List<Chave> chaves = dao.getLista();
    req.setAttribute("chaves", chave);
    return "sistema?logica=ListaChaves";
}
}
```

**Código ChaveDAO:**

```
public class ChaveDAO {
private Connection con;

public ChaveDAO() {
    con = ConexaoBanco.getConnection();
}

// Método ADICIONA
public void adicionar(Chave c) {

    String query = "insert into chaves (nome, numero) values (?, ?);";

    try {
        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();

        p.setString(1, c.getNome());
        p.setString(2, c.getNumero());

        p.execute();
        p.close();
        System.out.println("Gravado!");
        con.close();

        // issso aqui manda pro BD
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Método LISTA
public List<Chave> getLista() {
    try {

        List<Chave> chaves = new ArrayList<Chave>();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from chaves");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Chave chave = new Chave();
            chave.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            chave.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            chave.setNumero(rs.getString("numero"));
            chaves.add(chave);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return chaves;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Você está chamado o p.executeQuery() antes de setar os valores, primeiro faça o p.setString(1, c.getNome()) e depois o execute.

Comment: O que o @DiegoSchmidt e também é desnecessário/danoso o `p.execute()` no final. Além disso, para mudar os dados, você deveria usar `executeUpdate`. A premissa do `executeQuery` é que ele não vai alterar a base de dados; ou seja, de toda a DML, apenas o subconjunto DSL

Answer (score 1):

O Diego Schmidt achou um outro bug no seu código no comentário que ele fez, mas ainda não foi o seu bug. Depois de ajeitar o bug da questão, seus dados não estariam atualizados, ou daria um erro ao inserir nulos, ou daria erro por não terminar de fazer os *bindings* da `PreparedStatement`.

O seu erro se deu por você estar usando diretrizes de atualização de dados na sua consulta. No caso, você está usando `insert`. Todas as diretrizes de atualização de dados (mais padrões) são:

- `insert`
- `update`
- `delete`

Isso aí junto com a chamada DQL forma a DML. Alguns preferem dizer que DML seria só essas atualizações, vai depender do autor/SGBD/documentação que está definindo os termos.

> - DQL => *data query language*
> - DML => *data manipulation language*

A DQL estaria inclusa apenas a parte de seleção/consulta de dados; tudo que envolvesse `SELECT` estaria aqui. Então a parte de `FROM`, `JOINS` e `WHERE` seriam classificadas como DQL. O `preparedStatement.executeQuery` só aceita DQL.

Para conseguir usar a DML que está fora da DQL (chamemos essa linguagem de DML\DQL), você deveria usar `preparedStatement.executeUpdate`.

### Resumo

- ouça o Diego, prepare antes de executar
- DQL => `executeQuery`
- DML\DQL => `executeUpdate`
- mais sobre essas siglas: [O que são as siglas DDL, DML, DQL, DTL e DCL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262867/91)

---

#### *sidenotes*

Uma outra sublinguagem de SQL é a DDL, *data definition language*. Essa é a parte do SQL responsável por criar e alterar tabelas e *views*. Para executar qualquer DDL, você não pode usar nem o `executeQuery` nem o `executeUpdate`, mas sim `statement.execute`. Também não vejo muito sentido em preparar uma DDL, por isso que pus `statement`, não `preparedStatement`.