# Criar uma foreign key com dois campos varchar

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou encontrando bastante dificuldade em criar uma `foreign key` entre duas tabelas, cujo tipo é `varchar`:

```
ALTER TABLE netmap ADD CONSTRAINT fk_IP FOREIGN KEY ( IP ) REFERENCES ipvalidos (IPS);
```

O erro é:

> Failed to execute SQL : SQL ALTER TABLE netmap ADD CONSTRAINT fk_IP FOREIGN KEY ( IP ) REFERENCES ipvalidos (IPS) failed : Cannot add foreign key constraint

Antes de tentar fazer a `foreign key`, eu dei o `describe`, que está assim:

**ipvalidos**

```
Field   Type          Null  Key     Default     Extra
IPS     varchar(255)  NO    PRI
```

**netmap**

```
Field   Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra
IP      varchar(15)     NO      MUL     
MAC     varchar(17)     NO      PRI     
MASK    varchar(15)     NO  
NETID   varchar(15)     NO      MUL
```

Preciso que fazer uma comparação entre essas tabelas, mas não sei por onde começar.

Comment: Mas em uma tabela (`netmap`) o campo tem tamanho 15 (`varchar(15)`) e na outra tabela (`ipvalidos`) o campo tem tamanho 255 (`varchar(255)`)! O problema provavelmente está relacionado a isso. E, na tabela `ipvalidos`, esse 'S' no nome do campo `IPS` por um acaso não indica plural, não é?

Comment: Eu li na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) que campos de tipo string participantes de uma foreign key não precisam ter o mesmo tamanho, mas precisam ter o mesmo *character set* e *collation*, e ambas as tabelas precisam estar no mesmo *storage engine*, e as tabelas não podem ser temporárias. Você tem o script [DDL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262868/86952) dessas duas tabelas, e chaves referentes?

Comment: @Pedro Gaspar, Já efetuei um `ALTER TABLE ipvalidos CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;  e ALTER TABLE netmap CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; `  Apareceu outro erro: `ALTER TABLE netmap ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_IP` FOREIGN KEY ( IP ) REFERENCES ipvalidos(IPS ) ; failed : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ocsweb`.`#sql-640_ba7c`, CONSTRAINT `fk_IP` FOREIGN KEY (`IP`) REFERENCES `ipvalidos` (`IPS`))`

Comment: Você já tem dados nessas tabelas? Tem algum `IP` na tabela filha (`netmap`) que não esteja na tabela pai (`ipvalidos`)?

Comment: @Pedro Gaspar, Sim tem. Por isso quero ainda insistir na relação entre as duas. A tabela _ipvalidos_ tem todos os ips validos, a _netmap_ tem os ips que estão em uso.

Comment: E por quais motivos os dois campos têm tamanhos diferentes?/

Comment: Nenhum motivo específico.

Comment: Então o campo `netmap.IP` armazena sempre apenas um único número IP, e o campo `ipvalidos.IPS` também armazena sempre apenas um único número IP, correto? Porque da forma como está, o campo sendo maior e tendo um 'S' no nome, dando ideia de plural, me fez pensar desde o início que você está usando o campo `ipvalidos.IPS` para armazenar uma lista de números IPs, mas, não é esse o caso então, certo? Porque se for, o problema está aí.

Comment: Perfeito @Pedro Gaspar! É uma relação de 1:1 mesmo, em campos únicos, sendo o `ipvalidos.IPS` chave primária.

Comment: Mesmo ambos os campos sendo identicos, não consigo fazer a `Constraint`

Comment: E você tem certeza que todos os IPs da tabela filha têm um correspondente na tabela pai? Porque é o que esse erro parece indicar... As duas tabelas têm muitos registros? Você consegue excluir todos os registros para fazer um teste e tentar incluir a chave com as tabelas vazias?

Comment: Sim, na `ipvalidos`, Pai, tenho todos os ips válidos na minha rede, utilizados e/ou vagos, na `netmap`, filha, eu só tenho os ips utilizados na rede.

Comment: Você consegue apagar o conteúdo das tabelas, ou fazer uma cópia da base e apagar, ou recriar a base como um teste, para verificar se o erro continua ocorrendo mesmo sem registros nas tabelas? Se deixar de ocorrer o erro, o problema era no relacionamento dos registros pais-filhos mesmo. Como você está fazendo para se certificar que todos os filhos têm correspondência na tabela pai?