# Webservice retornando erro

Tags: php, web-service

Meu webservice está retornando um erro que eu ainda não consegui resolver.

Segue o código:

```
`<?php
$dns = ‘mysql:host=localhost;dbname=diagnosys_db’;
$user = ‘user_name’;
$password = ‘user_password’;
try{
 $db = new PDO ($dns, $user, $pass);
}
catch( PDOException $e){
 $error = $e->getMessage();
 echo $error;
}
?>`
```

O erro retornado é o seguinte:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
>   /storage/ssd4/128/11623128/public_html/db.php on line 2

Comment: Você declarou uma variável chamada $password, mas quando está instanciando o PDO está utilizando uma variável chamada $pass, tente substituir $pass por $password

Comment: Já analisou os tipos de aspas que está utilizando? [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/411319/127729) você encontra uma explicação rápida sobre uns erros causados por aspas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá

Você declarou uma variável chamada $password, mas quando está instanciando o PDO está utilizando uma variável chamada $pass, substitua $pass por $password

Ajuste também as aspas, segue abaixo o código com os devidos ajustes.

```php
<?php
$dns      = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco-nome';
$user     = 'usuario-do-banco';
$password = 'senha';


try{
 $db = new PDO ($dns, $user, $password);

}
catch( PDOException $e){
 $error = $e->getMessage();
 echo $error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Mesmo depois dessa correção o erro continua (apesar de que foi uma ótima observação, muito obrigado!)

Comment: Copia e cola o código que postei, e altere apenas as informações referente a conexão com o banco de dados.